# Connecting to SQL Server Express 2017 via Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, toad

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2017 Express via Python and tried the following code:

```
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                 'Server=USYD1WCXS3\SQLEXPRESS;'
                 'Database= tempdb;'
                 'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM db_name.tablename')
    for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

I also tried the following:

```
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 17.0};'
                 'Server=USYD1WCXS3\SQLEXPRESS;'
                 'Database= tempdb;'
                 'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM db_name.tablename')
    for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

and

```
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                 'Server=USYD1WCXS3\SQLEXPRESS;'
                 'Database= tempdb;'
                 'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM db_name.tablename')
      for row in cursor:
      print(row)
```

This is the error I am getting every time

> InterfaceError
>
> Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   1 import pyodbc
>   2 conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 17.0};'
>   3                       'Server=USYD1WCXS3\SQLEXPRESS;'
>   4                       'Database= tempdb;'
>   5                       'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
>
> InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: You haven't shown the traceback of the issue

Comment: meaning the error?

Comment: You're not connecting to "Toad" - that's just another front-end / GUI tool - what you're doing is **connecting** to the **core SQL Server database engine** (here the Express edition) - just like Toad also does.